# How do I go to the next value in a list using a for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I want my list which is currently: [0] to increase by 1 each time the loop repeats.

```
card_number = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

for i in range(10):
    print(card_number[0])
```

I want it to print each string in my list - eg: `A, 2 ,3 , 4...`

Comment: Change `print(card_number[0])` to `print(card_number[i])`?

Comment: `print(card_number[i])` instead.

Comment: This is a non-issue even for python beginner, the use of range is rather puzzling that OP never state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `in` operator on list itself, python automatically iterates list for you.

```
card_number = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

for i in card_number:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tip: you shouldn't use 10, you should use range(len(card_number))

But I prefer this mode

```
card_number = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

for c in card_number:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Debugging**:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(card_number[0])  # notice this line
```

It prints the `0th` element, that is `A` in the list for `10` times, certainly not what you intended.

**Hence**:

Use the counter variable `i` instead of the index value `0`:

```
card_number = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

for i in range(len(card_number)):  # Use len(card_number) instead to avoid accidents
    print(card_number[i], end = " ")
```

**Suggested** (one-liner):

Using `in` operator, that works for each element in the list.

```
print(', '.join([elem for elem in card_number]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Comment: `print(', '.join(str(elem) for elem in card_number))` should be enough

Comment: @Netwave Indeed, just wanted to show a possible fix before the suggested one.

Comment: I meant that there is no need for the intermediate list